# Pointer can't get data

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers

I want get the row number of data, but the pointer `CvMat* data, CvMat* responses` get nothing in `main()`. The minimal, complete and varifiable example is showed as follow:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"

#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>  
#include <iomanip>

#define ATTRIBUTES_PER_SAMPLE 9
#define NUM_OF_ALL_SAMPLES 950

using namespace std;

int read_data( CvMat* data, CvMat* responses )
{
    float temp=1.0;

    data = cvCreateMat( NUM_OF_ALL_SAMPLES, ATTRIBUTES_PER_SAMPLE, CV_32F );
    responses = cvCreateMat( NUM_OF_ALL_SAMPLES, 1, CV_32F );

    for(int line = 0; line < NUM_OF_ALL_SAMPLES; line++)
        for(int attribute = 0; attribute <= ATTRIBUTES_PER_SAMPLE ; attribute++){

            if(attribute < ATTRIBUTES_PER_SAMPLE){
                CV_MAT_ELEM(*data, float, line, attribute) = temp;
            }
            else if(attribute == ATTRIBUTES_PER_SAMPLE){
                CV_MAT_ELEM(*responses, float, line, 0) = temp;
            }

        }


    return 1;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    CvMat* data = 0;
    CvMat* responses = 0;

    int ok = read_data(data, responses);

    int nsamples_all = data->rows; // <--------- error happens here 

    cvReleaseMat(&data);
    cvReleaseMat(&responses);

    return 0;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is

> Unhandled exception at 0x013715c2 in opencv_pointer.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000014.

My compiler is VS2008. Why do the the pointer `CvMat* data, CvMat* responses` get nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are passed by *copy* so the pointer `CvMat* data` in the function is *copy* of the pointer you pass in from main. Any changes you make to it are local to the function. When you assign it a value using `cvCreateMat()` that value is not reflected back to the `CvMat* data` in `main()` so it gets lost when the function returns.

If you want changes to the parameter to be "passed back" you need to pass in the pointers by *reference*:

```
// pass variables by reference using &
int read_data(CvMat*& data, CvMat*& responses)
```

Now changes made to the parameters inside the function happen to the variables you passed in from outside the function - the pointers are not copied, they are referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Because the arguments are passed by value. You can use reference to have callee modify caller's local variables like this (add `&`):

```
int read_data( CvMat*& data, CvMat*& responses )
{
    // the same code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `data` and `responses` are declared to be passed by value, which means any modification on themselves (not the pointee) inside `read_data()` would not affect the variables in `main()`, their value are still the initialized value `0`.

You could change the parameter type to be passed by reference (or passed by pointer, relevant code needs adjustment for it).

```
int read_data( CvMat*& data, CvMat*& responses )
                     ~             ~
{
    ...
}
```